# Erro ao tentar logar em PHP

Tags: php, login

Criei um **login** básico com `php` para o site que estou desenvolvendo, mas ao tentar logar ocorre o seguinte erro **"usuário ou senha inválidos"**, este erro está no código, mas não entendo porque ocorre, pois já conferi os dados do banco, como usuário, senha e nome do banco, estão todos corretos.

Meu código esta assim:

**login.php**

```
     <?php 
        $cnpj    = $_POST['cnpj'];
        $senha   = $_POST['senha'];
        $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
        $db      = mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'treinamentos') or print(mysqli_error());
        $sql     = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0) {
           echo "Usuário ou senha não conferem" ;
           echo '<br><br><a href="../index.html">Voltar</a>';
           session_destroy();
        }else {
           header("Location:index.html");
        }
     ?>
```

**formulário html**

```
<form method="POST" action="php/login.php">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="username">CNPJ</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" name="cnpj">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Acessar" id="acessar" name="acessar">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Se tiverem uma ideia de o que pode estar causando tal erro, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Da onde vem a variavel n1 e n2? Faltou partes importantes do seu arquivo de verificaçao.php, coloque ai...

Comment: Sei que é fora da questão perguntada, mas acho importante lembrar. A variável `$cnpj` está entrando na query sem qualquer tipo de tratamento, o `mysqli_*` não é magico e pode continuar tão vulnerável quanto o `mysql_*`. Além disso [recomendaria mudar o `rand()`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php), mas isso não é tão importante. Agora sobre o problema está faltando informações no código, como o `$n1` e `$n2`.

Comment: No verificacao.php um trecho diz: Se (alguma coisa) 'login nao efetuado' e sair OU 'login nao efetuado' e sair. De um jeito ou outro, será apresentado um erro e mata a aplicação ali. Pode não ser o problema da página, mas  tem uma inconsistência aí

Comment: @RubioFalcao, adiciona ele no código para podermos ajudar melhor

Comment: Não é uma resposta formal, só estranhei você ter um if que aponta para o mesmo fluxo independente da avaliação

Comment: Ok, irei adicionar a parte que falta

Comment: pois é, se $n1 for diferente de $n2  Login não efetuado   senão  Login não efetuado, ambos com Login não efetuado. E tem uma } a mais no if else.

Comment: Alterei o código para que possam entender melhor.

Comment: Os parâmetros de `mysqli_select_db()` e `mysqli_query()` estão trocados. O primeiro parâmetro é sempre a `$conexao`. Antes da edição esse erro não existia.

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Irei editar

Comment: @Inkeliz Funcionou, já até editei a pergunta. Se quiser pode adicionar a resposta. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @R.Gasparin boa noite, apenas a título de sugestão: como já foi mencionado, já que você está usando o `mysqli`, passe a usar as `prepared statements` para sanitizar a entrada de dados na sua query. Do jeito que está, seu código está suscetível a [SQL Injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Ok, irei adotar a sugestão. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe vários pequenos erros...

**1. `mysqli_select_db()`**

Você está usando como `mysqli_select_db('treinamentos', $conexao)` e na verdade é ao contrário, segundo a documentação é esperado que seja:

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php)

Logo, você está invertendo os parametros, deve utilizar então:

```
mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'treinamentos')
```

**2. `mysqli_query()`**

O mesmo erro anterior, é esperando que utilize:

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

Ao invés de usar `mysqli_query($sql, $conexao)`, deve utilizar:

```
mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Além disso, como comentado, atente-se ao fato de não está tratando os parâmetros adequadamente.

Utilize ao menos o `mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $cnpj)`, [ver documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), desde que o `mysqli_set_charset` esteja configurado corretamente será suficiente. Uma outra opção é utilizar o `mysqli_prepare` ele irá exigir maiores modificações no código atual, [recomendo ver este guia](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).