# como inserir dados em duas tabelas no mesmo instante

Tags: php, html, mysql

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para inserir dados em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo , bem eu não sei se está certo da maneira que estou fazendo ele não está dando nenhum erro mas também não inseri nada .

O código abaixo.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
    $pedido = $_POST['pedido'];
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];

    //echo "$nome_usuario - $email_usuario";

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO pedido (mesa) VALUES ('$numero_mesa')";
   mysqli_query( $query1 );

    $id = mysqli_insert_id();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO item_pedido (pedido,quantidade) VALUES ({$id}, '$pedido', '$quantidade')";
    mysqli_query( $query2 );

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Peixaria</title>
    <style>
        .add {
            text - decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.add,add2{ text-decoration:none;}
#selecionados input,#selecionados2 input{ margin:10px;}
</style>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
        <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
    <main>
        <form>
            <header>
                <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
            </header>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <input type="text">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Mesa:</span>
                    <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
                </label>
                <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
                <div class="pedidos">

                    <select name="pedido,quantidade" id="pedido,quantidade"class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
                        <option  >Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
                        <option >Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
                        <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
                        <option >Sardinha Frita</option>
                        <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
                        <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
                        <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>
                </div>
               <br>
                <div name="pedido,quantidade" id="pedido,quantidade" class="pedidos">

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <select class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola 1l</option>
                        <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
                        <option >Bare 2l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Uva</option>
                        <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
                        <option >Sprit</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola </option>
                        <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
                        <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
                        <option >Guaraná Baré</option>
                        <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
                        <option >Suco Manga</option>
                        <option >Suco Pessego</option>
                        <option >Suco Uva</option> 
                        <option >Suco Maracujá</option>
                        <option >Suco Laranja</option>
                        <option >Suco Caju</option> 
                        <option >Agua Mineral </option>
                        <option >Agua com Gas </option>
                        <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
                        <option >Limonada Natural</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>

                </div>
<b>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(".add").on('click',function(){ 
            var cont=0;
            var holder = $(this).closest('.pedidos');
            holder.find(".selecionados input").each(function(){
                if($(this).val()==holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html()){
                    cont++;
                }
            });
            if(cont>0) { 
                alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");
            } else{
                holder.find(".selecionados").append(
                    "<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='" + 
                    holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html() + 
                    "' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>"
                );
            }
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é similar ao que [respondi nesta questão.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177764/erro-ao-tentar-logar-em-php/177837#177837) *A diferença é que não está usando o modo procedural, mas vamos lá.*

Primeiro você cria a conexão:

```
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
```

Se as credenciais estiverem corretas não há erro, portanto o `$link` é quem possui a acesso à classe do MySQLI e que possui acesso ao MySQL.

Agora você precisa utilizar:

```
$link->funcao();
```

Isso ocorre porque é o `$link` que está com a classe do MySQLI, então para que consiga utilizar as funções, deve utilizar:

```
$link->query($query1);
```

Isso é aplicável para todas as funções, por exemplo:

```
$link->insert_id;
```

> Não são todas as funções do MySQLI que vão utilizar o `$link`.

Não consigo tecnicamente explicar, mas você quiser obter o resultado de uma quer por exemplo usar o `mysqli_fetch_array`, você deve utilizar o a variavel que possui o resultado.

Por exemplo:

```
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
$resultado = $link->query('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 1');

$resultado->fetch_row();
```

Você não deve utilizar `$link->fetch_row()`, um jeito fácil de ver o que você precisa é ver na documentação, lá diz exatamente quem deve ser chamado. ;)

Acho que conseguiu entender a logica.

Comment: mais ou menos mas , aonde realmente estaria o erro no meu código sendo que não aparece erro mas também não inserir nada no bd

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de passar todos os parâmetros necessários para a função `mysqli_query`.

Altere essas linhas:

```
mysqli_query( $query1 );
mysqli_query( $query2 );
```

Para:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query1);
mysqli_query($link, $query2);
```

Comment: mesmo colocando o link não  aparece nada no banco de dados quando o formulário é enviado .

Comment: tente remover o value {$id} e deixar somente: `INSERT INTO item_pedido (pedido,quantidade) VALUES ('$pedido', '$quantidade');`

Comment: mesmo assim acho que tem outro erro além desse que não tá funcionando.

Comment: Verifique também se `$numero_mesa`,`$pedido` e `$quantidade` não estão vazios. Pois testei aqui sem verificar o REQUEST_METHOD e inseriu normal.

Comment: teria como manda o que você testou

Comment: Aqui está o código, claro, alterei as informações do `banco de dados`, `tabela` e `colunas`. Link: http://pastebin.com/zuzMReRJ